# Group a list of strings by similar values

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, grouping

I want to group a list of strings by similarity.

In my case (here simplified cause this list can be huge) it's a list of path to zip files like this:

```
["path/002_AC_HELICOPTEROS-MARINOS_20230329_210358_145T3_21049_00748_DMAU.zip",
 "path/002_AC_NOLAS_20230326_234440_145T2_20160_06473_VMS_UMS.zip",
 "path/002_AC_HELICOPTEROS-MARINOS_20230329_211105_145T3_21049_00748_FDCR.zip",
 "path/002_AC_HELICOPTEROS-MARINOS_20230329_205916_145T3_21049_00747_VMS_UMS.zip",
 "path/002_AC_NOLAS_20230326_235504_145T2_20160_06473_FDCR.zip"]
```

I would like to group the strings in that list by a key, but I don't know yet how to define it (I guess with a lambda but I can't figure it out) in order to get a result list like this:

```
[["path/002_AC_HELICOPTEROS-MARINOS_20230329_210358_145T3_21049_00748_DMAU.zip",
  "path/002_AC_HELICOPTEROS-MARINOS_20230329_211105_145T3_21049_00748_FDCR.zip"],
 ["path/002_AC_HELICOPTEROS-MARINOS_20230329_205916_145T3_21049_00747_VMS_UMS.zip"],
 ["path/002_AC_NOLAS_20230326_234440_145T2_20160_06473_VMS_UMS.zip",
  "path/002_AC_NOLAS_20230326_235504_145T2_20160_06473_FDCR.zip"]]
```

To give you an example the first grouping key would be:

```
*_HELICOPTEROS-MARINOS_20230329_*_21049_00748_*.zip
```

second would be:

```
*_HELICOPTEROS-MARINOS_20230329_*_21049_00747_*.zip
```

and third:

```
*_NOLAS_20230326_*_20160_06473_*.zip
```

Comment: Why should the third list in the result not be grouped with the first two?

Comment: because they have different AC name : HELICOPTEROS-MARINOS vs AC_NOLAS

Comment: No, the third one also has HELICOPTEROS-MARINOS (I refer to the third line in the desired result).

Comment: oh sorry the ending number before .zip differs, i've edited the post to be more precise

Comment: Why are 00747 and 00748 in different groups but 210358 and 211105 are in the same group?

Comment: 00747 and 00748 are session numbers and 210358 and 211105 are time but i don't care about this so that's why i've  putted a * instead in my example key !

Comment: Can your AC name have the `_` in it?

Comment: No it's only "-"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about extracting the required `key` to be used to group the file names together.

Here's a simplified function `extract_features` that assumes that there are no additional `_` in the filename apart from its standard format. It can be modified as per your file name convention to extract the required key, and then group them together using the [itertools.groupby()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
from itertools import groupby

def extract_features(f):
    filename = f.split('/')[-1]
    parts = filename.split('_')
    return (parts[2], parts[3], parts[6], parts[7])

data = ["path/002_AC_HELICOPTEROS-MARINOS_20230329_210358_145T3_21049_00748_DMAU.zip",
 "path/002_AC_NOLAS_20230326_234440_145T2_20160_06473_VMS_UMS.zip",
 "path/002_AC_HELICOPTEROS-MARINOS_20230329_211105_145T3_21049_00748_FDCR.zip",
 "path/002_AC_HELICOPTEROS-MARINOS_20230329_205916_145T3_21049_00747_VMS_UMS.zip",
 "path/002_AC_NOLAS_20230326_235504_145T2_20160_06473_FDCR.zip"]

data.sort(key=extract_features)
output = []

for k, g in groupby(data, extract_features):
    output.append(list(g))

print(output)
```

**Output:**

```
[['path/002_AC_HELICOPTEROS-MARINOS_20230329_205916_145T3_21049_00747_VMS_UMS.zip'],
['path/002_AC_HELICOPTEROS-MARINOS_20230329_210358_145T3_21049_00748_DMAU.zip', 'path/002_AC_HELICOPTEROS-MARINOS_20230329_211105_145T3_21049_00748_FDCR.zip'],
['path/002_AC_NOLAS_20230326_234440_145T2_20160_06473_VMS_UMS.zip', 'path/002_AC_NOLAS_20230326_235504_145T2_20160_06473_FDCR.zip']]
```

e.g. for the `path/002_AC_HELICOPTEROS-MARINOS_20230329_210358_145T3_21049_00748_DMAU.zip` the sorting key would be `('HELICOPTEROS-MARINOS', '20230329', '21049', '00748')`

Answer (score 1):

A more flexible approach, would be to use *regex* combined with [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) :

```
import re
from itertools import groupby

pat = r'^(.*)_(\d{8})_\d{6}_(\d+T\d)_(\d{5})_(\d{5})_[A-Z_]+\.zip$'
​
def sort_keys(x):
    groups = re.match(pat, x).groups()
    return (groups[0], groups[1], groups[2], groups[3], groups[4])

sdata = sorted(data, key=sort_keys)
out = [list(g) for k, g in groupby(sdata, key=sort_keys)]
```

*NB : To have more/less sort keys, you just need to add/remove parenthesis in the pattern.*

Output :

```
[['path/002_AC_NOLAS_20230326_234440_145T2_20160_06473_VMS_UMS.zip',
  'path/002_AC_NOLAS_20230326_235504_145T2_20160_06473_FDCR.zip'],
 ['path/002_AC_HELICOPTEROS-MARINOS_20230329_205916_145T3_21049_00747_VMS_UMS.zip'],
 ['path/002_AC_HELICOPTEROS-MARINOS_20230329_210358_145T3_21049_00748_DMAU.zip',
  'path/002_AC_HELICOPTEROS-MARINOS_20230329_211105_145T3_21049_00748_FDCR.zip']]
```

Comment: thx for your answer works very good too i think i will test performance of both approach on larger list like 50000 elements in list, do you want to make a bet ahah ?

Comment: I'm not good at bets but I would say @Jay's approach would be faster on small and/or large datasets. Make sure to keep us posted ;)

Comment: to measure i used time.time() and printing difference so for your solution on 138 path to sort it takes : 0.0025501251220703125 and for @Jay it takes 0.0006692409515380859

Comment: I updated my answer to make the code a little faster. Can you check again ?

Comment: a bit better : 0.0012137889862060547